# Access the host port dynamically and set it to DockerLabels in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I am trying to access the host port and set it as `dockerLabels` while defining the Cloud Formation some thing like below:

```
"dockerLabels": {"SERVICE_PORT": "${service_port}"},
"portMappings": [
  {
    "containerPort": {
        "Ref": "ContainerPort"
    },
    "hostPort": ${service_port}
  }
],
```

I was trying to access these ports later through aws-sdk for service discovery.

Answer (score 0):

Service ports are dynamic and Cloudformation doesn't keep up with ever-changing values. If you can work with static ports, then declare it as a cfn parameter and reference it in your snippet. You can then use that port in your service discovery setup